# htaccess preventing sqlite database being downloaded

Tags: php, htaccess, apache2

I have a VPS, running apache2 on Debian 6.

Created a file called .htaccess on the web root, which included:

```
<Files ~ "\.db$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

<FilesMatch "\.db$">
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Can still manually download the database.db file that exists in the same directory as the .htaccess file. Restarted Apache2, same.

What gives?

Comment: Any reason why your sqlite file has to be placed inside your web root?

Comment: at this point no, but this is making me mad that I can't get htaccess to work how it should

Comment: What's the [`AllowOverride` setting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride) for that directory? Also, for future reference, you don't need to restart Apache for .htaccess changes to take effect.

Comment: SQLLite database is for Android Applications. It has no relation with httaccess. httaccess file resides in the XAMPP/WAMP/LAMP folder you installed. You could be asking to download the SQL file. It can be done by clicking Export button in you phpMyAdmin page. If I am wrong then please state how you are facing problem.

Answer (score 1):

Send it a 404!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*).db [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.html [R=404,L]
```

Comment: or 301 to root page